# Double value from sum query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm currently using access to keep track of my stockportfolio. It contains ~20 tables. I use a query to include the most important data to export into excel. Two data tables include two names each that are identical but with different values. This results in the sum om Mkt_Value, Contr and Vol (shown in code) to recieve a double valuation.

From googling I think it revolves around having to use subselects and something other than left join. The problem is I have mostly used query wizard for this query so I am unsure how to tackle the problem. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

I posted an excerpt of the code containg the four tables causing the problem: tbl_datum (Date table), tbl_positions, tbl_ARMSpositions and tbl_ARMSgreeks.

Thanks in advance!

```
SELECT
tbl_Positions.ARMSNAME, 
tbl_Positions.Uploaddate, 
Sum(tbl_ARMSpositions.Mkt_Value), 
Sum(tbl_ARMSpositions.Contr), 
Sum(tbl_ARMSgreeks.Vol)


FROM 
((tbl_Datum INNER JOIN tbl_Positions ON tbl_Datum.Datum = tbl_Positions.UploadDate) 

LEFT JOIN 
tbl_ARMSpositions ON (tbl_Positions.Uploaddate = tbl_ARMSpositions.Value_Date) AND (tbl_Positions.ARMSNAME = tbl_ARMSpositions.Name)) 

LEFT JOIN 
tbl_ARMSgreeks ON (tbl_Positions.Uploaddate = tbl_ARMSgreeks.Value_Date) AND (tbl_Positions.ARMSNAME = tbl_ARMSgreeks.Name)


GROUP BY 
tbl_Positions.ARMSNAME, 
tbl_Positions.Uploaddate;
```

Comment: it sounds like you either have a Cartesian product, or your DB has some duplicate data, which is making it seem like a Cartesian product.  I can't tell, without seeing your data.  
You can check your own data by looking for duplicates of 'Value_Date' or 'Uploaddate'.  Otherwise, test by modifying your query, remove the sums & group by. Then look at your data to see if you are getting duplicated rows. Once you isolate the duplicate (or Cartesian product), we can tell you how to eliminate it.

Comment: Yes I'm getting two rows when group by/sum is removed. There are a few items that come in with the same name and different mkt_values in tbl_ARMSpositions. The problem i think is that these names also show up in tbl_ARMSgreeks (although they don't have the field mkt_value). I can't remove the rows manually since I need to keep the other data coming in and I can't rename 1 of the rows because i want them to sum.

The problem is that when i use count instead of sum it shows up as 4 items instead of 2 for the duplicate rows.

Comment: You don't need to manually remove the rows from the database.  You could use `DISTINCT` to roll-up the duplicates in `tbl_ARMSpositions`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your data, I'll have to guess.  Based on your description and comment, it sounds like you have a Cartesian product because of the data in your table `tbl_ARMSpositions`. I think this modification to your query should fix it:

```
SELECT
   tbl_Positions.ARMSNAME, 
   tbl_Positions.Uploaddate, 
   Sum(tbl_ARMSpositions.Mkt_Value), 
   Sum(tbl_ARMSpositions.Contr), 
   Sum(tbl_ARMSgreeks.Vol)
FROM 
   (  (tbl_Datum INNER JOIN tbl_Positions ON tbl_Datum.Datum = tbl_Positions.UploadDate) 
      LEFT JOIN 
      (SELECT DISTINCT Value_Date, Name FROM tbl_ARMSpositions) AS tbl_ARMSpositions ON (tbl_Positions.Uploaddate = tbl_ARMSpositions.Value_Date) AND (tbl_Positions.ARMSNAME = tbl_ARMSpositions.Name)
   ) 
   LEFT JOIN 
   tbl_ARMSgreeks ON (tbl_Positions.Uploaddate = tbl_ARMSgreeks.Value_Date) AND (tbl_Positions.ARMSNAME = tbl_ARMSgreeks.Name)
GROUP BY 
   tbl_Positions.ARMSNAME, 
   tbl_Positions.Uploaddate;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! 
Hm, getting a syntax error on joint operation. Tried to fix it but still not working, it's annoying that access doesn't have a decent tool for errors. Any ideas what it might be?

Comment: Sorry, I needed to alias that embedded query (when you put a query inside parentheses, it needs an alias) LikeThis.  I fixed my code above.